# js event is not triggering using jquery mobile and phoengap for android

Tags: cordova

I am developing application using phonegap in eclipse for android .I have created folder structure in assets->jquery.mobile  folderI have put jquery library files jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js etc.and assets->www folder put html files .I have include jquery library file in html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
```

In html file I have written code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() { 
$('body').bind( 'taphold', function( e ) { 
alert( 'You tapped and held!' ); 
e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
return false; 
} ); 
$('body').bind( 'swipe', function( e ) { 
alert( 'You swiped!' ); 
e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
return false; 
} );
} );
```

I have added phonegap jar and put plugins xml file in xml folder  can anybody tell what is problem how to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `<\script>`

The following index.html runs successfully for me. (Note, I'm running with phonegap-1.3.0 and jquery-mobile-1.0, but I would expect the older versions to run fine for this program.)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>PhoneGap Demo With JQuery Mobile</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="pgandjqm-style-override.css" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() { 
$('body').bind( 'taphold', function( e ) { 
alert( 'You tapped and held!' ); 
e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
return false; 
} ); 
$('body').bind( 'swipe', function( e ) { 
alert( 'You swiped!' ); 
e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
return false; 
} );
} ); 
</script>
    </head>
  <body >
  </body>
```

Comment: will i need main.js file to run above application application in eclipse for android

Comment: No, the index.html is complete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  the versions of your reference files are too old. Please update them. Latest: phonegap->2.4, jquery->1.9.1, jqm->1.3.
Second, you need check if your phonegap project have been created in correct way. The latest phonegap you download will have a test project which has been configurated perfectly. Also you can use the official command-line way to create your project with standard template.
Third, you may use 'ondeviceready' event to bind your test function. If it did not work, your phonegap configuration must be wrong and you need check again.